Close small circuit with ESP32 (Validation on custom PCB design)
Hi folks,
I am currently working on a multifunctional PCB design for my custom-designed ESP32 breakout board.
Background:
I have an ESP32 on a custom PCB that has lots of sockets to plug in these little PCBs shown here. The idea is that each of these PCBs gets one GPIO pin broken out from the ESP32 and a variety of different voltage sources (which are all on the same GND). This way, I can simply choose my voltage by moving a jumper (JP3).
This PCB should not only give me the GPIO pin to connect to but also provide two more functions, selectable by a jumper on JP1. Another jumper (JP2) is to optionally enable a pull-up or pull-down resistor on the GPIO.
The three functions to choose from:

GPIO: Directly use the GPIO pin for any purpose.
DET: Detect a 12V signal and give the GPIO (as a binary sensor) feedback.
CL: Close a small circuit, e.g., the external controllable on/off switch of a Victron Energy charger.

My question is about the CL function:
The idea is that I want to be able to close an external small circuit without the need for a large, mechanical, and current-hungry relay. With the jumper JP4, I want to have the option of where to connect. I want to either connect the IO pin with GND directly, or with JP3 where I can choose which voltage source I want to connect to. If I leave no jumper on JP3, I could just connect the IO pin with the pin right beside it (pin 2 on J2).
Does this even make any sense?
In my head, this should work fine if U2 would be or behave like a relay, but can I use an optocoupler for this circuit as well? Or do I have to use a MOSFET or SSR instead?
Once again, the idea behind this is that the Victron Energy charger gives me multiple options to use the two wires to externally turn the device on or off:

"A remote-controlled on/off switch or a relay contact can be connected to the two-pin plug. Alternatively, connection H (right) of the two-pin plug can be connected to a positive battery terminal or connection L (left) of the two-pin plug to the negative battery terminal (or, for example, to the body of a vehicle)."

This is the cable you can buy from Victron Energy to get the same results but by connecting the adapter to another battery, but not something like a GPIO. I want to replicate this device but enabled by GPIO.
My current schematic looks like this:

The current PCB design looks like this:



Sorry, I'm not really following your schematic very well. This schematic looks incomplete as there are global nets, like Power, IO, UP, DOWN, DET, CL, and GPIO, that come from nowhere and are inputs to other nets and devices. It seems like the only way the user can use JP2 is if the 3V3 rail is connected on JP3. Then again, I really don't know what purpose JP3 even provides other than pull-up/down at JP2. I don't know how 12V specifically can get detected as you mentioned with DET since there's no ADC or voltage sensing that can make that measurement.

@Colin sorry if this schematic looks incomplete to you! It's my first real schematic and I guess I used the global nets wrong... I just used it to flag/name parts of the net for my better overview when designing the PCB layout. So please just think of theme here as naming labels. What would be the correct way to do it?

@Colin about the jumpers: JP3 gives me the option to get different output voltages on one of the pins on J2 for powering sensors/leds/... JP2 is just optional to be used as pull-up or pull-down when I want to use the GPIO as sensor input. DET works already just fine (tested) as I have the optocoupler U1 which gets activated if there are 12V present at the IO labeled pin (common GND) and therefore the GPIO gets connected with +3V3 functioning as a binary_sensor once again. Does this make any sense to you? If something is still unclear please let me know and I will try to explain it;)
